# looping through worksheet command buttons and change visibility

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a code to make a number of buttons visible depending on a cell value

I have 10 command buttons all are invisible and I want to show only the first x
 x is the value of cell "A1" in "Sheet1" (will be from 1 to 10)
 Command buttons names are default names (CommandButton4, CommandButton5, ... , CommandButton13)

Note: I'm working with a worksheet not a userform

This is my code but i need something shorter and more pro and efficient

```
Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CommandButton() As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CommandButton = Array("CommandButton4", "CommandButton5", "CommandButton6", "CommandButton7",     "CommandButton8", "CommandButton9", "CommandButton10", "CommandButton11", "CommandButton12", "CommandButton13")

    For i = LBound(CommandButton) To LBound(CommandButton) + Sheet1.Range("A1").Value - 1

        Sheet1.Shapes(CommandButton(i)).Visible = True

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Need ur help plz

Comment: That's better than most of the code I've seen to do this. I'd rename the buttons in the series though.

Comment: This code does look decent already.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comment you should rename your buttons. That just makes things easier.

You could for example name them "btn1", "btn2", "btn3" ....
Your code is ok and i can't see major errors. I don't know if you want to add new buttons later.

If so i would recommend something more generic. If you rename the buttons to "btn1"... then you could use something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()
Dim btn As OLEObject, name As String, i As Long
i = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value + 1
For Each btn In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    name = btn.name
    If btn.OLEType = xlButtonOnly And InStr(name, "btn") = 1 Then
        If Int(Right(name, Len(name) - 3)) < i Then
            btn.Visible = True
        Else
            btn.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

So you can add new buttons name them with the "btn.." pattern and you don't have to change your Code.